# Convert to a SAS Time

Tags: sas

I have a txt file containing time in this format 161058.262  which is intended to be 16:10:58.262.

I cannot find an INFORMAT that will turn this value into the correct SAS numeric time value.  TIME12.3 will convert into a numeric.  It gets stored as 579824520 and displays using format TOD12.3 format as 22:22:00.000

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Please elaborate a little but more your question and maybe post a part of your file, what context and language are you using it in etc... You can always import the file into MS Excel and process the time there, or write an AutoIt script to fix the date formatting...

Comment: Seems like he's using SAS, given he tagged this SAS?

Answer (score 5):

I would do a quick transformation to make an existing informat work. For example, your format is the same as what `B8601TM` expects, except for the dot that separates the fraction of a second. You can strip out the dot from your string and then apply the informat.

Example:

```
data test;
    input t $10.;

    format tt TOD12.3;

    tt = inputn(compress(t, , "kn"),  "B8601TM9.3");

datalines;
161058.262
; run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a specific informat, but you certainly can work in colons, or do the math to make it into a time using HMS.

```
data test;
informat t_pre $10.;
input t_pre $;
t = input(catx(':',substr(t_pre,1,2),substr(t_pre,3,2),substr(t_pre,5)),TIME12.3);
*CATX concatenates using a delimiter, so this generates a string like 16:10:58.262;
*Then converts to TIME12.3;
put t= TIME12.3 t_pre=;
datalines;
161058.262
;;;;
run;

data test;
input t_pre;
t = hms(floor(t_pre/10000),floor(mod(t_pre,10000)/100),mod(t_pre,100));
*HMS generates a time value from hours, minutes, seconds, and allows milliseconds in the seconds;
*So we use combination of division and modulo to separate the number into component parts;
put t= TIME12.3;
datalines;
161058.262
;;;;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

### code

```
data _null_;
    input int_val $10.;
    format time_val timeampm15.3;
    time_val = input(
                 prxchange('s/(\d?\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\.\d\d\d)/$1:$2:$3/',
                          -1, int_val),
                 time10.3);
    put int_val
    @15 time_val timeampm15.3
    @30 time_val 10.3;
datalines;
000000.001
012345.678
12345.678
161058.262
235959.999
run;
```

### log

```
000000.001    12:00:00.000 AM     0.000
012345.678     1:23:45.600 AM  5025.600
12345.678      1:23:45.670 AM  5025.670
161058.262     4:10:58.200 PM 58258.200
235959.999    11:59:59.900 PM 86399.900
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```